Testing PHP CodeIgniter 3 controller with PHPUnit
I want to unit test my PHP website, which uses the outdated framework CodeIgniter 3. CodeIgniter 3 uses the MVC pattern, and each page on the website corresponds to a public method in a controller.
I wrote a simple unit test (to check and see if the page's title is set to "About Us") for one of the pages/methods as a proof of concept. It tests this line:
$this->data = set_page_title('About Us', $this->data);
... by making this assertion...
$this->assertEquals( $titleGlobal, 'About Us' );
But boy does it take a lot of setup code to test this simple assertion.
I got the test for this working, but it's ugly. I suspect code review is going to reveal...

instead of creating stubs at the top of the file, I should do it with native PHPUnit methods such as $this->createMock(), and

I need to replace all my functions with dependency injected classes and methods, for easier stubbing/mocking


Would like someone good at PHPUnit to confirm this and add some details. Thanks a lot :)
The name of the controller is General, and the name of the page/method is about_us.
Just looking for a code review of tests/controllers/GeneralTest.php. Some other code is included for background.
tests/controllers/GeneralTest.php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH') ) {
    define('BASEPATH', true);
}

class CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        $this->output = new Output();
    }
}

class Output {
    function enable_profiler() {
        // intentionally blank since this is a test double
    }
}

function set_auth_variables( $data ) {
    // intentionally blank since this is a test double
}

function load_page_with_great_races_sidebar( $uri, $data ) {
    // intentionally blank since this is a test double
}

$titleGlobal = '';
function set_page_title( $title, $data ) {
    global $titleGlobal;
    $titleGlobal = $title;
}

final class GeneralTest extends TestCase {
    protected function setUp(): void {
        define( 'APPPATH', 'application/' );
        define( 'ENVIRONMENT', 'development' );
        require_once( 'application/config/constants.php' );
        require_once( 'application/controllers/General.php' );
    }

    public function test__about_us__has_correct_title() {
        global $titleGlobal;
        $controller = new General();
        $controller->about_us();
        $this->assertEquals( $titleGlobal, 'About Us' );
    }
}

application/controllers/General.php
<?php

require_once APPPATH . 'core/MV_Base_Class.php';

class General extends MV_Base_Class {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function about_us() {
        $this->data = set_page_title('About Us', $this->data);

        load_page_with_great_races_sidebar('general/about_us', $this->data);
    }

    // ...
}

application/core/MV_Base_Class.php
<?php

class MV_Base_Class extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data = null;

    public function __construct() {
        // Load system/core/Controller, which loads system/core/Loader. This creates the database connection and loads helper files, among other things.
        // If there is an SQL connection problem, the line below is where the code will die.
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data = set_auth_variables($this->data);

        // If ?r= is used in the link, record this in a session variable. ("r" stands for referrer and is a marketing tracking variable.) Later, if the person creates a company or signs up to volunteer, the "r" variable will be associated with their signup, which helps populate /managers/signup_sources and similar reports.
        if ( isset($_GET['r']) ) {
            $_SESSION['http_referrer'] = $_GET['r'];
        }

        if ( ENVIRONMENT == 'development' ) {
            $this->output->enable_profiler(true);
        }

        // Adds 0.04s to every page load
        if ( ENVIRONMENT == 'development' ) {
            require_once('../ci_dev/vendor/autoload.php');
        } else {
            require_once('../ci_main/vendor/autoload.php');
        }
    }
}

application/helpers/mv_login_helper.php
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

function set_auth_variables($data) {
    $obj = &get_instance();
    $manager_id = $obj->session->userdata('manager_id');

    // Set auth variables even if user isn't logged in. That way you don't get "variable not set" errors, and we save ourselves from having to check for that.
    $data['auth'] = null;

    if ( $manager_id ) {
        $data['auth']['manager'] = $obj->manager_model->get_manager_by_id($manager_id);

        if ( $data['auth']['manager'] ) {
            $company_id = $data['auth']['manager']['manager_company_id'];

            $data['auth']['company'] = $obj->company_model->get_company_by_id($company_id);
        } else {
            $data['auth'] = null;
        }
    }

    if ( isset($_SESSION['admin_sticky_company_id']) ) {
        if ( is_admin($data['auth']) && $_SESSION['admin_sticky_company_id'] != $data['auth']['company']['company_id'] ) {
            $data['auth']['company'] = $obj->company_model->get_company_by_id($_SESSION['admin_sticky_company_id']);
        }
    }

    // If company has been deleted, unset admin_sticky_company_id to avoid Control Panel redirect loop.
    if ( ! isset($data['auth']['company']) && isset($_SESSION['admin_sticky_company_id']) ) {
        unset($_SESSION['admin_sticky_company_id']);
    }

    return $data;
}

// ...

application/helpers/mv_view_helper.php
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

function load_page_with_great_races_sidebar($page_name, $data) {
    // $data is required. If the user is logged in, we need the auth variables.

    $data = html_escape($data);

    $obj = &get_instance();
    $data['great_races'] = $obj->race_model->get_upcoming_sidebar_races();

    $obj->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $obj->load->view('templates/great_events_header', $data);
    $obj->load->view($page_name, $data);
    $obj->load->view('templates/great_events_footer', $data);
    $obj->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}

// ...

application/helpers/mv_misc_helper.php
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

function set_page_title($page_title, $data) {
    $data['page_title'] = $page_title . ' - ' . MV_BROWSER_TITLE;

    return $data;
}

// ...

PHPUnit output

